# Keep first layer of folders from Get-ChildItem when moving

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I am working on some PowerShell script that automatically moves folders and files from the 'X-Drive' folder and move it into the 'Old' folder which also is inside the 'X-Drive' folder, but I want it to keep the first layer folders only, all what's inside can be moved but only the folder needs to be kept, but it also needs to be in the 'Old' folder.

```
$exclude = @('Keep 1', 'Keep 2')
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\X-Drive" -Recurse -Exclude $exclude |
    Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-0) } |
    Move-Item -Destination "C:\X-Drive\Old" -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enumerate the subfolders of `C:\X-D_rive`, then move their content to corresponding subfolders in `C:\X-Drive\old`, e.g. like this:

```
$refdate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
Get-ChildItem 'C:\X-Drive' -Directory -Exclude $exclude | ForEach-Object {
    $dst = Join-Path 'C:\X-Drive\old' $_.Name
    If (-not (Test-Path -LiteralPath $dst)) {
        New-Item -Type Directory -Path $dst | Out-Null
    }
    Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -Recurse | Where-Object {
        $_.LastWriteTime -lt $refdate
    } | Move-Item -Destination $dst
}
```

You may want to add `old` to `$excludes`, BTW.

The code assumes you're running PowerShell v3 or newer.

Comment: It works like a charm, but it doesn't move any files in it, is it so programmed or do i need to include it somewhere?

Comment: The sample code should move files that were last modified more than a day ago (`$refdate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)`). Adjust that reference date according to your requirements. Your original `(Get-Date).AddDays(-0)` doesn't make much sense, because that would move all files that weren't last modified in the future (i.e. all files), so you could just as well remove the condition.

Comment: No it wouldn't but i am testing it before using it. Many thanks for helping me out.